# onbeforeunload confirm dialog can be customised with custom dialog box with good design?

Tags: javascript

Can we override  the page leaving confirm  dialog with  custom designed dialog box like jquery UI dialog?

I'm trying  to implement it as :

> var warning = true;
>   var v_leavemsg = "Are you sure want to leave page?";
>   window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
>
> function confirmExit() {
>      if (warning) {
>           // custom dialog FUNCTION CALL
>           f_customdialog(v_leavemsg);
>           return null;
>      }
>   }
>   
>   
>   function f_customdialog(msg) {
>      //EG. WE CAN USE JQUERY DIALOG HERE with "Yes" or "No" button
>      alert(msg);
>   }

Comment: Yes you can. You can tie any function to onbeforeunload, so you can show whatever dialog you want. If there's already a different event handler bound as well, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if there is a way you would have to stop code execution when `onbeforeunload` calls given function.

What comes up to my mind is that you could return `false` on first call and create custom dialog which would, if user want to leave website, trigger `onbeforeunload` event with changed `onbeforeunload` function which would return true then by default.

That way you could possible "trick" default behaviour.

Problem is that `onbeforeunload` is synchronous and any custom dialog is not. It is working with native dialog because it executes synchronously.

Not sure if this will work though.

Comment: Hi, Mr Br, Thank you  for your answer. But it wont work. it will simply alerts "false" and no any function call is working. I just wanted to override the default page leaving confirm  dialog with  jquery UI dialog box  to make look like custom dialog box.